# Why is MS TestExplorer in VS2015RC not discovering Tests and showing test run result details?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2015

The test explorer (MS-Test) kind of stopped working. It won’t discover any of my tests or sometimes only some of it. When I right click on my test and run it, the output window says “Run test finished: 1 run (time)”, but the test explorer would only display “Last Test Run Failed” (see screenshot), without information about which test or assert failed. I’ve tried restarting the VS, which I thought solved the issue once, but not currently. I’ve also tried build, rebuild, but I just can’t get it working again? Any idea what might help? All of this was working fine until early morning today... [image]

[image]

Comment: What does the Output window say?

Comment: When I run the entire test class, output window says "Run test finished: 24 run (timeTaken)". When I did clean and then rebuild, output window did say "xx test found" or sth similar.

Answer (score 0):

Test Explorer has problems understanding test projects if they are build for x64 or x86, and solution is targeting a different platform.

Also, under Test > Test Settings > Default Test Architecture select appropriate value and then clean and rebuild.